# Getting the dimensions of an svg path without using bounding box

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jquery-svg, librsvg

Would there be a way to get the dimensions of an svg path and display it in a div? The bounding box is not an option as it is buggy in Webkit when it comes to bezier curves. I am doing a modification of svg-edit btw: https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

This is what im currently using.

```
    <script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){getDimensions()},10);

    function getDimensions() 

    {

  svgNode = svgCanvas.getSelectedElems()[0];


var getw = svgNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var geth = svgNode.getBoundingClientRect().height;
getw= parseInt(getw);
geth= parseInt(geth);
 document.getElementById('heightbox').innerHTML = geth;
 document.getElementById('widthbox').innerHTML = getw;



}

    </script>
```

Unfortunately thre bounding box is unreliable. Any ideas other than the bbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RaphaelJS has a utility method for determining the bounding box of a path - http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathBBox

```
var dims = Raphael.pathBBox(pathString);
var getw = dims.width;
var geth = dims.height;
```

Comment: Its different than the one im using right? Any ideas on how the code would be modified using your solution?

Comment: It doesn't use the SVG bounding box API, rather it uses an algebraic calculation of the bounding dimensions for the specified path. It is a static method that takes an SVG-style path string. You should be fine to include this library in your project and use the method directly.

Comment: Try var dims = Raphael.pathBBox(svgNode.getAttribute('d')); Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/ReEmu/2/ The string representing the path is stored on the 'd' attribute.

Comment: does raphael.js an open source?